# Creating a balanced binary tree with a string of letters

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to create a balanced tree with a string of letters. If you put "ABCDE" for string, your code is expected to give an output something like this.

INPUT : "ABCDE"

OUTPUT :

```
 .......................................................
                            +                                                              
            +                              E                              
    +              +              --              --              
A      B      C      D      --      --      --      --      
.......................................................
```

The book suggests me to first create an array of one-node tree whose root will be each character of the string. Then, make a three-node tree out of each pair of one-node trees, making a new + node for the root which will result in a forest of three - node trees.

I know this problem is a stepping-stone to ultimately write the Huffman tree.

I'm having trouble putting the three-node tree back into the array with one-node trees and then make a 7-node tree by combining the two three-node trees and so on.

Below is my code,

```
import java.util.*; // for Stack class

class StringNode {
  public char iData; // data item (key)
  public StringNode leftChild; // this node's left child
  public StringNode rightChild; // this node's right child

  StringNode(char d) {
    iData = d;
  }

  public void displayNode() // display ourself
  {
    System.out.print('{');
    System.out.print(iData);
    System.out.print("} ");
  }
} // end class Node

class STree {
  private StringNode root; // first node of tree
  public String sequence;

  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  public STree() // constructor
  {
    root = null;
  } // no nodes in tree yet

  public void makeBalanceTree() // creating a balanced tree
  {
    StringNode array[] = new StringNode[sequence.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++)
      array[i] =
          new StringNode(sequence.charAt(i)); //fill array with node holding each character as key

    STree forest[] = new STree[array.length]; //make a forest of trees
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) { //store each node as the root of the tree
      forest[j] = new STree();
      forest[j].root = array[j];
    }

    int count = sequence.length();
    while (count == 0) {}
  }

  public void displayTree() {
    Stack globalStack = new Stack();
    globalStack.push(root);
    int nBlanks = 32;
    boolean isRowEmpty = false;
    System.out.println("......................................................");
    while (isRowEmpty == false) {
      Stack localStack = new Stack();
      isRowEmpty = true;

      for (int j = 0; j < nBlanks; j++) System.out.print(' ');

      while (globalStack.isEmpty() == false) {
        StringNode temp = (StringNode) globalStack.pop();
        if (temp != null) {
          System.out.print(temp.iData);
          localStack.push(temp.leftChild);
          localStack.push(temp.rightChild);

          if (temp.leftChild != null || temp.rightChild != null) isRowEmpty = false;
        } else {
          System.out.print("--");
          localStack.push(null);
          localStack.push(null);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < nBlanks * 2 - 2; j++) System.out.print(' ');
      } // end while globalStack not empty
      System.out.println();
      nBlanks /= 2;
      while (localStack.isEmpty() == false) globalStack.push(localStack.pop());
    } // end while isRowEmpty is false
    System.out.println("......................................................");
  } // end displayTree()
} // end class Tree

public class StringTreeApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value;
    STree theTree = new STree();
    theTree.sequence = "ABCDE";
    theTree.makeBalanceTree();
    theTree.displayTree();
  } // end main()
} // end class TreeApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the book is making it harder for you than necessary by recommending creating an array of `StringNode`s up front.

If you have a String, you know that the "middle" character is going to be the `iData`; the characters preceding it are going to be in the left tree; the characters following it are going to be in the right tree.

As such, you should be able to construct a `StringNode` as follows:

```
StringNode buildStringNode(String sequence) {
  if (sequence.isEmpty()) return null;

  int middlePos = (sequence.length() + 1) / 2;
  char iData = sequence.charAt(middlePos);

  StringNode result = new StringNode(iData);
  result.leftChild = buildStringNode(sequence.substring(0, middlePos));
  result.rightChild = buildStringNode(sequence.substring(middlePos + 1));
  return result;
}
```

This "automatically" combines the child trees with the parent tree. Your `makeBalanceTree()` method is then simply:

```
void makeBalanceTree() {
  root = buildStringNode(sequence);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually took a different approach(not using recursion) and came up with something which I think should work but it didn't. Could I ask you about this via chat ?

Comment: It would be better if you post it as a new question; others may have better insights than me.

Comment: I got it! just in case you're interested. After for loops,                            int count = sequence.length();
    while(count!=1){
     int fill =0;
     for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
      if(i%2==1){
       StringNode plus = new StringNode('+');
       plus.rightChild = forest[i].root;
       plus.leftChild = forest[i-1].root;
       forest[fill].root = plus;
       fill++;
      }
      if(i%2 ==0 && i==count-1){
       forest[fill].root = forest[i].root;
       fill++;
      }
      
       
      
     }
     count = fill;
     
    }
    root = forest[0].root;

Comment: your answer gave me the foundation. greatly appreciated